# Android 4.0.4 does not show up in my Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4. I can't run apps (from Eclipse) on my phone because in the Android SDK Manager, I can only install Android 4.0.3 or Android 4.1.
Android 4.0.4 is not listed, so I can't choose it as target in my Eclipse project.
In my understanding, I need to install Android 4.0.4 in the SDK Manager, otherwise I can't run apps on my Android device.
Is there a workaround? Why is Android 4.0.4 not in the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: API 15 and earlier will run just fine on your phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4.0.4 is the build on your device. The versions listed in the SDK manager are the ones in which a change was made to an API, whether it be a bug fix or a feature addition/removal.

You can target any Android SDK and still run on your device, as long as the minimum SDK is specified to be equal to or lower than the version your phone is running. You can check [here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) for the API version and their corresponding Android builds.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I need to install the Samsung USB driver.